# MSBuild hangs forever when Fody writes assembly

Tags: msbuild, fody-propertychanged

In my solution many project make use of *Fody* to inject the *PropertyChanged* weaver. Unfortunately at the end of the build, when *Fody* starts writing the final assembly, the process hangs and cannot be recovered.

This is the MSBuild command I am executing:

```
set msbuildemitsolution=1
msbuild MyCompany.App.sln /t:Build /fl /flp:logfile=buildoutput.txt;verbosity=diagnostic /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:UseSharedCompilation=false
```

This is the log of the build:

```
AfterCompile:
   Beginning transformation.   
   Transformation succeeded 
FodyTarget:
    Fody: Fody (version 3.0.3.0) Executing
    Fody: ProjectDirectory: 'C:\Dev\Client\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell\'.
    Fody: AssemblyPath: 'C:\Dev\Client\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell\obj\Debug\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.exe'
    Fody: Found path to weavers file 'C:\Dev\Client\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell\FodyWeavers.xml'.
    Fody: SolutionDirectory path is 'C:\Dev\'
    Fody: Finding weavers
    Fody: FindAddinDirectories:
    Fody:   No PackageDefinitions
    Fody:   Scanning SolutionDir/Packages convention: C:\Dev\packages'.
    Fody:     Fody weaver file added 'C:\Dev\packages\PropertyChanged.Fody.2.5.4\netclassicweaver\PropertyChanged.Fody.dll'
    Fody:   Skipped directory from Nuget Config since it could not be derived.
    Fody:   Scanning the MsBuildThisFileDirectory parent: C:\Dev\'.
    Fody:   Skipped scanning 'C:\Dev\Tools' since it doesn't exist.
    Fody:   Skipped NuGetPackageRoot since it is not defined.
    Fody: No Weaver project file found.
    Fody: Finished finding weavers 25ms
    Fody: Creating a new AssemblyLoadContext
    Fody: Reference count=209
    Fody: References:   *follows long list of references...*
    Fody: Found debug symbols at 'C:\Dev\Client\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell\obj\Debug\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.pdb'.
    Fody: Weaver 'C:\Dev\packages\PropertyChanged.Fody.2.5.4\netclassicweaver\PropertyChanged.Fody.dll'.
    Fody:   Initializing weaver
    Fody:   Loading 'C:\Dev\packages\PropertyChanged.Fody.2.5.4\netclassicweaver\PropertyChanged.Fody.dll' from disk.
    Fody: Can't find 'FSharp.Core, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    Fody: Can't find 'System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
    Fody: Can't find 'System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
    Fody: Can't find 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
    Fody: Can't find 'System.Numerics, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
    Fody: Can't find 'System.Transactions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
      Fody/PropertyChanged:   Executing Weaver
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.ViewModels.SplashScreenViewModel
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             Model
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     Model skipped since call already exists
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.Model.ShellWindowModel
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             ProgramProvider
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     ProgramProvider
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             UiEnabledContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     UiEnabledContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             SizingContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     SizingContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             ProgramHeaderRegionVisibility
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     ProgramHeaderRegionVisibility
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             EnvironmentVersion
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     EnvironmentVersion
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             EnvironmentVersionFontFamily
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     EnvironmentVersionFontFamily
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             EnvironmentVersionFontColor
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     EnvironmentVersionFontColor
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             EnvironmentVersionFontSize
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     EnvironmentVersionFontSize
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             Title
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     Title
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             RibbonSelectedIndex
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     RibbonSelectedIndex
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             IsBusy
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     IsBusy
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             IsTaskButtonsBusy
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     IsTaskButtonsBusy
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             ShellContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     ShellContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             ConsoleEditingContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     ConsoleEditingContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             Icon
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     Icon
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             IsOptionNavigationEnabled
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     IsOptionNavigationEnabled
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.Model.SplashScreenModel
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             LoadingMessages
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     LoadingMessages
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             SelectedMessageIndex
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     SelectedMessageIndex
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             NameVersion
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     NameVersion
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             Environment
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     Environment
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             EnvironmentColor
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     EnvironmentColor
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.ViewModels.ShellWindowViewModel
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             Model
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     Model
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.Model.ShellContext
      Fody/PropertyChanged:             IsInConsoleMode
      Fody/PropertyChanged:                     IsInConsoleMode
      Fody/PropertyChanged:   Finished 'PropertyChanged' in 162ms
      Fody/PropertyChanged:     Removing reference to 'PropertyChanged'.
    Fody:   Adding weaving info
    Fody:   Finished in 5ms
    Fody:   Writing assembly to 'C:\Dev\Client\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell\obj\Debug\MyCompany.App.Client.Shell.exe'.
```

It would hangs forever in this state, if I try to cancel the build with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> I get this message:

```
Attempting to cancel the build... 
warning MSB4220: Waiting for the currently executing task "Fody.WeavingTask" to cancel.
```

The process will keep trying to cancel the build every 10 secs or so, unsuccessfully. The MSBuild task becomes unkillable and I need to restart my machine in order to try kicking another build!

The project makes use of the following:

- Fody.3.0.3
- PropertyChanged.Fody.2.4.0

The msbuild version I am using is *16.4.0.56107*

I tried to update to the latest Fody version, that did not help.

I know this might be a long shot; if anyone has any tip/idea on how to investigate this, please share it. Thank you.

-- EDIT --
If I remove PropertyChanged and  Fody from the failing project then the Solution can complete the build. What can possibly cause Fody to hang?

Comment: Having this issue, not able to solve by any means. Does anyone get a breakthrough?

Comment: Out of curiosity... do you have a file with no extension in the root of your hard drive? Look for something like `C:\Program` or `c:\Progra~1`

Comment: No, I don't have such file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't been able to isolate the issue; considering that Fody wasn't working only on one of our projects, I ended up replacing Fody and PropertyChanged with the .Net implementation provided by the `BindableBase` class

```
    private string title;
    public string Title 
    { 
        get => title;
        set => SetProperty(ref title, value);
    }
```

---

Not sure if this can help, however we noticed that some interference can come from file without extension in the root of the hard drive. 
Look from something like `c:\Progra~1` or `c:\Program` and rename it or remove it

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that using the latest compilers with a totally outdated version of Fody causes this - Fody (via Mono.Cecil) probably just can't cope with the generated IL.

Comment: In my case, I tried to update to the latest version of Fody as well - no success